# When using a scanner to read a file, why must the scanner be in the method?

Tags: java, file, stack, java.util.scanner

I've got a printer file, that prints all of the contents of a file. I know, advanced stuff.
Now I can make the program successfully run by declaring the scanner object within my method the calls the file which is an object variable in the call.

My problem is that when I declare the File and Scanner within my constructor it just returns to me the name of the file. Not sure if I explained that well.

```
public class Printer {
private File file;
private Scanner reader;


public Printer(String fileName) {
    this.file = new File(fileName);
    this.reader = new Scanner(fileName);
}

public void printContents() throws FileNotFoundException {

    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    reader.close();
}
```

and then my main

```
    public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Printer printer = new Printer("src/textfile.txt");
printer.printContents();
}
```

}

This just prints out src/textfile.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scanner gets the file name - and not the file.

```
public Printer(String fileName) {
    this.file = new File(fileName);
    this.reader = new Scanner(file); //note the change
}
```

This should help you get to the contents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it considered the better practice to declare it within the constructor or to do it within the method?

Comment: I would say method - to make sure you see the resource you opened and close it when not in use.